# Argument option using JCommander

Tags: java, command-line-arguments, jcommander

I'm new with `JCommander` and I'm trying to use it in my **JAVA Command Line Application**.

Fisrt thing I did is I've created my `CommandLineArguments` class.

Now, I'm trying to print options given with arguments in command line. But I think I'm missing something.

Here is my main class  :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {


    String[] argv={"-h","host"};
    CommandLineArguments arguments=new CommandLineArguments();
    JCommander commands= new JCommander(arguments);

    try {

        commands.parse(argv);

        System.out.println(commands.getParsedCommand());


    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        commands.usage();
    }
}
```

Once I run this class, I got  : `null` as output. Seems like `getParsedCommand()` is not used as it should.

Can someone tell me how to use `JCOmmmander` methods correctly so I can see options given with arguments?

What I'm trying to do here is, once the user runs `java -jar myApp.jar -port portNumber -h hostname -d database -c collection`  I wanna be able to get portNumber hostname database and collection value so I can establish a connexion and send queries.

Hope I was clear enough.

Ismail

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make a distinction between `commands` and `parameters`. In the example you give, you only need parameters.

The [first chapter of the JCommander documentation](http://jcommander.org/#Overview) provides a clear enough example of how to handle parameters. If your `CommandLineArguments` class is annotated as in the example, the parameter values should be correctly set in that class after calling `parse(argv)`.

Commands are explained in [a later chapter dealing with more complex command-line syntaxes](http://jcommander.org/#Complex).

Comment: It's not clear in the documentation. In the given example: `Assert.assertEquals(jct.verbose.intValue(), 2);` We know that value is `2`. How do we get the value when we use a temrminal and we don't know the given value ?

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't understand your confusion. Just calling `jct.verbose.intValue()` will give you the value. Add your `CommandLineArguments` class to the question and it might be able to give you a better answer.

Comment: Ok, You just answered my question. Merci

Comment: Yeah I did. Well,when youy told me : "Just calling `jct.verbose.intValue()` will give you the value" this was the answer I was looking for.